# What is Judaism's take on Kabbalah?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

I like to research religions and recently I started studying Kabbalah.

They claim that they've unlocked the key to the "upper worlds" and a few more claims such as there's no satan, no free will, no sin etc. even though some of their teachings makes sense yet the structure of their idea is... questionable!

What is Judaism's take on Kabbalah?

Comment: welcome! Judaism is not monolithic such that there is one "take on Kabbalah"... there is a vast gamut of beliefs regarding it ranging from full blown mystically guided sects (as Hasidism, and its many subdivisions are from its inception), to a complete denial of its legitimacy (such as Dardaim). I suggest narrowing the focus of your question in order to encourage the submission of answers on this broad topic.

Comment: Who are "they"?

Comment: Kaballah isn't really my thing but "What is Judaism's take?" is an extremely broad question. No one is required to study it but it is widely accepted as "legit". Is there something specific you want to know about it or are you more interested in a high-level overview?

Comment: What texts have you been using to study Kabbalah? The way you describe make it sound not Jewish, e.g., no free will, no sin. I strongly doubt authentic texts describe it this way. It takes many years of study to understand Kabbalah

Comment: You might find this series of 10 Youtube videos interesting: https://youtu.be/Zy2D35brm6M

Comment: Where did you get that there is no Satan, no sin etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to MiYodeya. Here is the standard view of Kabbalah as understood by most Orthodox Jews.

Judaism is a divine religion: it was taught to us by an All-Knowing G-d far beyond our comprehension. When G-d created the world and wrote the Torah, he obviously did so in ways we cannot begin to fathom. However, we can understand a little  bit beyond the plain appearance of reality and the plain understanding of Torah.

G-d revealed as much as a human could possibly understand to Moses, and he passed on that understanding to a select few disciples. They in turn passed on these teachings to a few select disciples. These teachings are commonly referred to by two names:

Kabbalah/Tradition: Because these matters can only be understood by transmission.

Torahs HaNistar/ The Torah of the Concealed: Because these matters relate to metaphysical concepts that are not tangible, and deeper meanings of verses beyond the surface meaning.

These teachings are not separate from Judaism, rather they are a deeper level of understanding. This leads to two corollaries:

1. The Kabbalah does not contradict Judaism in any fundamental ways.
2. Only one who has mastered the "revealed" part of Judaism is qualified to study it.

Because Kabbalah deals with matters that are by definition intangible, it must borrow terms such as "world", "light", "flow", etc. to simulate concepts  that are beyond our perception. In truth it is highly abstract, and many people struggle with the books written by non-Kabbalists to explain these matters a little bit. This has also meant that people without the correct background misunderstand Kabbalah and thus see it as heretical (I saw the answer on the Christianity SE that is a classic of that "genre.")

Unfortunately, the vacuum of understanding has created attempts by many to "explain" Kabbalah without the proper background. Some people are well meaning, but some are outright charlatans trying to get rich off people's naivete.

The false Messiah [Shabsai Tzvi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbatai_Zevi) misused Kabbalistic concepts to justify his fake claims and flagrantly transgress the Torah. That created a strong backlash to teaching Kabbalah to the masses that persists to this day.

Anyone who opens a "Kabbalah Center" or claims to teach Kabbalah to the masses is outside mainstream Judaism and not to be trusted. Especially anyone who attempts to use Kabbalah to raise money.

Anyone who treats Kabbalah as a separate religion from Judaism is not legitimate. Anyone who says that Kabbalah denies the existence of Satan or sin is flat-out wrong as wrong can be. (Although the Jewish -and therefore Kabbalistic- view of Satan is very different from the Christian/pagan dualist view.)

One last detail: Originally, Kabbalah was transmitted by word of mouth, as was the rest of the [Oral Torah](https://ohr.edu/explore_judaism/ask_the_rabbi/ask_the_rabbi/8087). Some parts of the Written Torah also contain Kabbalistic concepts, such as the visions opening the book of Ezekiel. As the Oral Torah began to be written down, so was the Kabbalah.

Comment: @ElectronSurf for another perspective, consider this: http://www.mesora.org/ToharHayihud.pdf

Comment: Was this “the standard view ofKabbalah as understood by most Orthodox Jews” for the first 2,000 years of Judaism?

Comment: @Alex Absolutely.

Comment: @Deuteronomy The link you provided is another classic misunderstanding of Kabbalah. The Sefirot are also creations of G-d.

Comment: @N.T. I have no desire to get into a debate about who does or does not actually misunderstand "Kabbalah". The essay is open to the reader to determine whether they find it compelling. That you do not is abundantly obvious, however there are other perspectives and this is one.

Comment: @N.T. Do you have sources from that time period to point to that can verify this?

Comment: @Alex The only written sources from Matan Torah until the Tannaim come from Tanach. Maaseh Merkava from Yechezkel is considered Kabbalah, in that its true meaning can only be taught one on one. See TB Chagigah Ch 2, esp. the quote from the book of Ben Sira (2nd century BCE) about not delving into mysteries. Source here: https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.13a.2?lang=he&p2=Ben_Sira.3.21&lang2=bi&w2=About&lang3=en

Comment: @Deuteronomy This point was debated at length centuries ago. The only people who still follow this opinion are the Teimanim. You will only find these descriptions of Kabbalah from its opponents, not its adherents.

Comment: @N.T. From personal experience and the communities I've been a part of, I know for a fact that these views are not restricted solely to those of Yemenite descent. And even were this so, that is altogether irrelevant. Truth does not become more true by virtue of the fact that the entire world agrees with it, nor less so even if the whole world disagrees with it. Once again, I wish to reiterate, that I am not interested in debating this topic. All the best.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, IDK why people down-voted me but it's okay, maybe I offended some here. A few questions; Why did your wrote G-d instead of God? I'm actually studying kabbalah through one of those "Kabbalah centers" by Dr. Michael Laitman, they advertise Yehuda Ashlag teachings and books, what do you think?

Comment: I asked the "instructors" there MANY TIMES about sin that they couldn't dodge the question anymore and the reply was: "According to Kabbalah, the only sin is not attributing something to the Creator, meaning that there is some other external force that acts besides Creator. Regarding humanity, there is no sin because they are completely governed by the Creator."

Comment: It's considered more respectful not to spell out G-d's name in full

Comment: Ashlag is controversial. He basically took Kabbalistic principles and turned them into some version of a Marxist doctrine. Anyone associated with Marx in any way is obviously not to be taken seriously, except in terms of how much damage they do. By promoting teaching what he called Kabbalah to the masses, he opened the door to anyone using Kabbalah to claim anything. If his center is anything like the Kabbalah Center of Los Angeles (where  I live), it is nothing more than a financial scam. I read the Bnei Baruch Wikipedia page, and nothing in there resembles  true Judaism or Kabbalah.

Comment: According to what you say, they deny the existence of free will. That is heresy according to Maimonides, and his definition has been accepted as authoritative by all Orthodox Jews. It also flies against everything in the Bible and the Kabbalistic works, as anyone with a passing familiarity with them knows. Not to mention that it goes against basic human experience. However, if I was going to make up a new religion with the goal of getting people to give me their money, I would tell them exactly what they want to hear, which is that there is no sin and they are therefore blameless.

Comment: @N.T. There are plenty of written sources from tannaim through early rishonim. What evidence is there from that time period? Rambam explicitly states what מעשה מרכבה is, and does not say kabbalah. Nor does the fact that its teaching must be limited indicate that it is kabbalah.

Comment: Please, direct me to authentic Kabbalah resources and books to study.

Comment: @ElectronSurf as stated in the answer, "Only one who has mastered the "revealed" part of Judaism is qualified to study it." So basically, start with learning Torah and learning about Judaism in general, and if you ever get to the point where learning Kabbalah is feasible, you'll know how to get there. Kabbalah is fundimentally *not understandable* unless you have a *complete* background in Torah study.

Comment: @Alex Rambam is outside the chain of transmission of Kabbalah. Look at Ramban, Rabbeinu Bechaye, Raddak on Gan Eden, etc.

Comment: @N.T. Those are sources within the last 1,000 years. We are looking for sources in the 2,000 year period prior to that.

Comment: I gave you those sources. Chagigah and Ben Sira. Sefer Habahir too.

Comment: @ElectronSurf As Esther said, you have to start with basic Judaism. Look into "kiruv" centers that specialize in teaching Judaism to beginners, such as Ohr Sameach and Aish Hatorah. What they teach you will be consistent with Kabbalah.

Comment: @N.T. Those sources don’t prima facie discuss kabbalah.

Comment: @Alex Call it what you want. Kabbalah is just  a term used for a class of knowledge. That class of knowledge definitely existed, and is discussed. Sefer Habahir is considered the first work of Kabbalah.